# Deserialize a tree, represented as a String

Tags: serialization, tree, deserialization

I'm looking for the most minimal piece of code to deserialize a tree.

Not a binary tree. A regular one. `Node.childs` is represented as a list. An `empty list` means a leaf.

My serialization method:

```
override
public String ToString()
{
    String toRet = "(";
    toRet += data;
    foreach (Node node in childs)
        toRet += " " + node.ToString();
    toRet += ")";
    return toRet;
}
```

The following tree will result in the String:

[image: Tree]

```
(A (B (F) (G)) (C) (D) (E))
```

Answer (score 0):

The trick is finding matching parens. Two matching parens define a subtree. The outermost matching parens give the whole tree. Following is a straight-forward solution, definitely not minimal in any sense of the word.

```
    private static int match(String s) {
        int balance = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++) {
            if(s[i] == '(') {
                balance++;
            } else if(s[i] == ')') {
                balance--;
            }
            if(balance == 0) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        throw new FormatException("Parens not balanced!");
    }

    public static Node Deserialize(String s) {
        if(s.Length == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        // Find the ending index of current node value
        int end = s.IndexOf(' ');
        if(end == -1) {
            end = s.IndexOf(')');
        }
        int i = end + 1; // skip past node value and seek for children
        List<Node> children = new List<Node>();
        while(i < s.Length) {
            if(s[i] == '(') {
                int j = Node.match(s.Substring(i));
                children.Add(Node.Deserialize(s.Substring(i, j + 1)));
                i += j;
            }
            i++;
        }
        return new Node(s.Substring(1, end - 1), children);
    }
```